# wireshark File export objects greyed out ver1.8.5

Tags: networking, wireshark

I tried to save all captured packets by selecting [File>export objects>HTML]

But in the version[1.8.5] which I am using , it is disabled(greyed out).

I want to enable it.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: greyed out image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to save all captured packets by selecting [File>export objects>HTML]

Nothing under "Export Objects" "saves all captured packets"; what they do is export an object being transferred in a particular sequence of packets.  I.e., they do not save the raw packets, they save the actual file/image/whatever that was being transferred in a particular sequence of packets.

This means that you have to select a packet that's part of a sequence that transfers an object in order for File -> Export Objects not to be disabled.

If you want to save the raw packets to a new file, in 1.8.x and later you want either:

- File -> Save if you have a live capture that you have not yet saved to a file or a capture file for which you've edited comments but not yet saved the changes;
- File -> Save As if you want to save all packets to a new file and have that file be the current file;
- File -> Export Specified Packets, if you want to save all packets to a new file and *not* have that file become the current file, or if you want to save some, but not all, packets.

Comment: I managed to save all packets and export objects. Because I want to save image files , I achieved my objectives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the capture (Red Square) before you can export packets. Once you do, the option should become available.